# Calculate 3 month Average on the base of CustomerID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate three month average sales in excel w.r.t customerid in excel. I tried by doing it by AverageIfs function but nothing helped.

```
A              B         C
Orderdate      sales    customerid
5/15/2019        7           1
5/15/2019        48.5        1
4/15/2019       92.94        1
3/17/2019     102.85         1
3/18/2019      49            1
3/18/2019     119.95         1
2/18/2019     58.96          1
1/20/2019      14.6         1
5/16/2019      17           6
4/15/2019     148.5         6
4/12/2019    912.94         6
3/17/2019   102.85          6
9/18/2018    22.34          6

Formula I tried: =AVERAGEIFS(B:B,C:C,C2)
```

output expected:

```
customerid      average(3 months)
1                    49.48         
6                   359.48
```

Comment: Show what you put in the averageifs()...

Comment: @SolarMike..I used : =AVERAGEIFS(B:B,C:C,C2)...where orderdate is column A, sales is column B and Customerid is column C respectively.

Comment: How did you get the 393.76 for customer 6? How do you define '3 months'? Most recent 3 months?

Comment: @GenWan: yes, Most recent 3 months for calculating average

Comment: So the average for customer 6 should be (912.94+148.5+17+0)/3 = 359.48. How did you get the 393.76? For customer 1, it should be 49.48. Most recent 3 months is 6/9/2019 to 7/8/2019 and 5/9/2019 to 6/8/2019 and 4/9/2019 to 5/8/2019.

Comment: @GenWan..because I have two orders in month of April..so for last three months it should be ( 17+148.5+912.94+102.85)/3=393.7

Comment: Yes, you have two orders in April. But why did you add 102.85?  3/17/2019   102.85          6;  This is from March.

Comment: @GenWan..yes u are right..my bad..so it should be 359.48 and 49.48

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196161/discussion-between-c-174-and-gen-wan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from today's date and the date 3 months ago (Make it dynamic):

Remember to change the cell format from General to Date. Otherwise, it will show [43563]

[image]

Next use the date as part of our filter:

[image]

[image]

Now you should get the most recent 3 months data:

[image]

---

***Copy the filtered data into a new spreadsheet***

***Copy the filtered data into a new spreadsheet***

***Copy the filtered data into a new spreadsheet***

---

Next Step: get the distinct customer ID:
[image]
[image]

You will get this:

[image]

Last Step:

Use the function "AVERAGEIF":

[image]

Done!